# How to generate multiple asscoated records for the same parent record in factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, factory-bot

Here is the definition for model user and user_level. A user has many user levels and a user level belongs to a user.

```
Factory.define :user do |user|

  user.name                  "Test User"
  user.email                 "test@test.com"
  user.password              "password1"
  user.password_confirmation "password1"
  user.status                "active"
  user.user_type             "employee"

end

Factory.define :user_level do |level|

  level.role                 "sales"
  level.position             "member"
  level.team                 1
  level.association          :user
end
```

@user_level = Factory(:user_level) generates one user_level record and its parent record in users table. What do I do if I need generate 2 user level records for one parent user record?

Any thoughts? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the user first, and then pass the same user to each factory create call:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
@user_level = Factory(:user_level, :user => @user)
@user_level2 = Factory(:user_level, :user => @user)
```

To do a quick sanity check, do an assert `equal` ([confirms it's the same object](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000430))

```
@user_level.user.should equal @user_level2.user
```